# Ember addon tests hang on "Waiting for runners" for Chrome and Firefox

Tags: ember.js, ember-testing, testem

Even I've mentioned Chrome in `testem.json` as the following, nothing happens:

```
{
  "framework": "qunit",
  "test_page": "tests/index.html?hidepassed",
  "disable_watching": true,
  "launch_in_ci": [
    "PhantomJS"
  ],
  "launch_in_dev": [
    "PhantomJS",
    "Chrome"
  ]
}
```

If only "Chrome" is written, console displays "Waiting for runners..." messsage and hangs.

`package.json`, `bower.json` and `testem.json` are all the same with my other projects, and all others are all running on Chrome.

Comment: Can you list available test runners? `testem launchers`

Comment: Ok, what happens if you run `ember t -s` and manually open the dedicated URL to launch tests (could look like `Open the URL below in a browser to connect.                                                                                        
http://localhost:7357/ `

Comment: works like a charm!

Comment: Maybe it´s related to the missing integrity attribute. Does your index.html contain  `<script src="testem.js" integrity="" ></script>`?
Source: [github issue](https://github.com/jonathanKingston/ember-cli-sri/issues/2)

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: What was it...? What is the fix?

Comment: After a clean startup, we've never faced it again.